# What is the meaning of "We can’t all fight habits as well as Calvin"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

By the way, is it appropriate if I turn to my Christian friends for an answer too?

***PS:** Here is the [source](https://ryanseys.com/blog/177-days-of-github/).*

Comment: Sorry, this question was asked without deep consideration. But it cannot be deleted. Anyway, there is no such thing as a stupid question, but here is such a thing as a question that wastes everybody’s time. Please let me know if anything I can do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not about Christianity.  Calvin, the boy in the comic strip, doesn't fight to *change* his habits, as most of us do; instead, he challenges the notion that he should take up *any* habits, *especially the so/called "good" habits* his mother might want him to acquire.